# Cookies error user authentication in next js on vercel deployment but working correctly on local host

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I have make a ecomerce store on next 13.4 and i am using cookies for authentication, the project is working correctly on local host but after deployment on vercel on login request the token is being stored in cookies but when calling /api/me route which will use token in cookies i am unable to access the token however the token is still there in cookies. It is only happening on vercel deployment not on local hospt

I have tried a lot but still the problem has not gone